# How to assign range of dates for each unique row in the dataframe

Tags: r, date, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a table which gives me the gpi score for a country by year.

**EXISTING DATA IN THE FINAL DATAFRAME I HAVE:**

```
gpi_year gpi_rank   gpi_country      gpi_score
2018        1       Iceland          1.096
2018        2       New Zealand      1.192
2018        3       Austria          1.274
.
.
.

2018        161     South Sudan      3.508
2018        162     Afghanistan      3.585
2018        163     Syria            3.6
```

However, I need to add a date range for each individual row.

Example:
I will check if the row has **2018** if yes then i would duplicate the record for that country for each date starting from **01-01-2018 to 31-12-2018** (because it is 2018). i.e **365 dates for one single country.**

Similarly if the row has the data for **2017** for any country then i need to duplicate the record for that country for each date starting from **01-01-2017 to 31-12-2017** i.e 365 dates for one single country.

**Example: NEED A SIMILAR OUTPUT:**

```
gpi_year  gpi_rank  gpi_country  gpi_score  date
2018        1       Iceland      1.096      01-01-2018
2018        1       Iceland      1.096      02-01-2018
2018        1       Iceland      1.096      03-01-2018
.
.
.
.
2018        1       Iceland     1.096       29-12-2018
2018        1       Iceland     1.096       30-12-2018
2018        1       Iceland     1.096       31-12-2018
2018        2       New Zealand 1.096       01-01-2018
2018        2       New Zealand 1.096       02-01-2018
2018        2       New Zealand 1.096       03-01-2018
.
.
.
.
2018        2       New Zealand 1.096       29-12-2018
2018        2       New Zealand 1.096       30-12-2018
2018        2       New Zealand 1.096       31-12-2018
```

**NOTE:** My data has **163** countries. Each country has the score for **2017** and **2018**.
**Therefore for each country i need to assign dates ranging from 1st Jan 2017 to 31st Jan 2017 and 1st Jan 2018 to 31st Jan 2018.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `data.table` with artificial dataframe:

```
library(data.table)

df <- data.frame("gpi_year" = 2018, "gpi_rank" = 1, "gpi_country" = "Iceland",
                 "gpi_score" = 1.096)

df <- setDT(df)[, .(gpi_rank = gpi_rank, gpi_country = gpi_country, gpi_score = gpi_score,
      date = seq(as.Date(paste0(gpi_year, "-01-01")),
                        as.Date(paste0(gpi_year, "-12-31")), by = "day"),
      gpi_year = gpi_year), by = 1:nrow(df)][, nrow := NULL]
```

Output:

```
     gpi_rank gpi_country gpi_score       date gpi_year
  1:        1     Iceland     1.096 2018-01-01     2018
  2:        1     Iceland     1.096 2018-01-02     2018
  3:        1     Iceland     1.096 2018-01-03     2018
  4:        1     Iceland     1.096 2018-01-04     2018
  5:        1     Iceland     1.096 2018-01-05     2018
 ---                                                   
361:        1     Iceland     1.096 2018-12-27     2018
362:        1     Iceland     1.096 2018-12-28     2018
363:        1     Iceland     1.096 2018-12-29     2018
364:        1     Iceland     1.096 2018-12-30     2018
365:        1     Iceland     1.096 2018-12-31     2018
```